# ghidra assigns local variable to register

Tags: assembly, android, ghidra, arm, shared-object

im reversing a android native library and im trying to understand how a token is generated the toke n is passed to a callback java method and i traced where the method is getting called from
this is the function that is calling the java method
note i renamed it to callvoidmethod

```
void CallVoidMethodV(JNIEnv *param_1,jobject param_2,jmethodID param_3,undefined8 param_4,
                    undefined8 param_5,undefined8 param_6,undefined8 param_7,undefined8 param_8)

{
  long lVar1;
  undefined auStack160 [8];
  undefined8 local_98;
  undefined8 uStack144;
  undefined8 local_88;
  undefined8 uStack128;
  undefined8 local_78;
  va_list local_70;
  va_list *ppvStack104;
  undefined *puStack96;
  undefined8 uStack88;
  va_list *ppvStack64;
  undefined *local_38;
  undefined8 uStack48;
  long local_28;
  
  lVar1 = cRead_8(tpidr_el0);
  local_28 = *(long *)(lVar1 + 0x28);
  puStack96 = auStack160;
  ppvStack104 = &local_70;
  uStack48 = 0xffffff80ffffffd8;
  uStack88 = 0xffffff80ffffffd8;
  local_98 = param_4;
  uStack144 = param_5;
  local_88 = param_6;
  uStack128 = param_7;
  local_78 = param_8;
  local_70 = register0x00000008;
  ppvStack64 = ppvStack104;
  local_38 = puStack96;
  (*(*param_1)->CallVoidMethodV)(param_1,param_2,param_3,&local_70);
  if (*(long *)(lVar1 + 0x28) == local_28) {
    return;
  }
```

the variable i am interested in is local_70 which is assigned register0x00000008 what is this value and what does it mean? and what is the variables with the word stack in it
also is there a way i can use a debugger on this library?